# PHP Zend Gdata error 400 when inserting row in spreadsheet

Tags: php, gdata, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I'm doing an small class to load spreadsheets and insert data in them but when I insert a row i retrieve an error:

> Expected response code 200, got 400 We're sorry, a server error
>   occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.

I have looking in this site and google and some people has this error when they trying to insert data with capital letters or spaces... i'm not trying to insert data like this so i suppose that this is not my error. I the code that is giving me problems:

```
try {
    echo $this->_spreadId . '<br>';
    echo $this->_defaultWorksheetId . '<br>';
    echo get_class($this->_spreadClient) . '<br>';
    $rowData = array('stuff' => 'smurf');
    $this->_spreadClient->insertRow($rowData, $this->_spreadId, $this->_defaultWorksheetId);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo '<br><pre>' . $exc->getTraceAsString() . '</pre>';
    echo '<br>' . $exc->getMessage();
}
```

The output of this script is:

```
tVe4Mr82qD3LRhubQrcLxMQ
od6
Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets

    #0 /home/sergi/projects/quiniela2gdocs/lib/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://spreads...', Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://spreads...', Array, 'post('insertEntry('insertRow(Array, 'tVe4Mr82qD3LRhu...', 'od6')

   Expected response code 200, got 400 We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.
```

Another method of this class is creating the spreadsheet and it's doing well, so i think there aren't connecting issues with gDocs.

Some help is welcome.

Lots of thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which has arisen due to the presence of spaces in the array. Remove spaces helped me:

```
$rowData = array('stuff' => 'smurf'); - your code
$rowData = array('stuff'=>'smurf'); - my code
```